# How can I print a random sample (with random.sample(range(x,y), z)) using a for-loop in a SINGLE line of code in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, random

I am trying to print 4 letters that are randomly selected from the alphabet. How can I accomplish this using "for" in a single line of code?

Previously I did it using a small block of code in a for-loop, but I want to do it using only a single line of code.

This is what I did in the past:

```
for i in random.sample(range(97, 124), 4):
    print(chr(i), end='')

OUTPUT: 'fgaj'
```

Now, I am trying to compress this into a single line of code, like this:

```
print(chr(i) for i in random.sample(range(97, 124), 4))
```

However, I receive the following output:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10d10e1b0>
```

Why is it not printing 4 randomly selected letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output tells you exactly what's going on. `chr(i) for i in random.sample(range(97, 124), 4)` is a generator. Enclose it in brackets (`print([chr(i) for i in random.sample(range(97, 124), 4])` to print the letters in a list, or use unpacking (`print(*(chr(i) for i in random.sample(range(97, 124), 4))`) to directly consume the generator.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. This is the first time I see unpacking (I've seen code using the star `*` but never knew what it meant). What does it do exactly? I ask because when I used unpacking like you showed me, it printed the letters separated by a space (`z v e d`). When I tried enclosing the entire line in brackets to remove the spaces like so: `(unpacked).replace(' ', '')`, it returned a syntax error: `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here`

Comment: So my question is, is there a short and easy way to unpack without the spaces? I say "short and easy" because if it was long and hard, it would defeat my initial purpose of wanting the code in a single line.

Comment: Unpacking passes in each element of the generator as a separate argument to `print`, which is why there are spaces. Since these are characters, you should be able to `sum` the generator to create a string without spaces in it.